# I get a "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method" error for anything with autopostback=true on one of my pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, jscript, autopostback

I have a .NET application with the following aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>
<%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" tagprefix="telerik"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTest" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="rblTest_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph1" runat="server" Visible="False">
        Some text
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I then have a C# method as follows:

```
protected void rblTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rblTest.SelectedValue == "2")
        ph1.Visible = true;
    else
        ph1.Visible = false;
}
```

Below is where the crash occurred. It crashes any time I use a control that has autopostback=true. I use the same syntax on about 15 other forms and those all work just fine. Am I missing a property somewhere or is there something wrong with my method? I originally had an UpdatePanel around the controls and I plan on adding it again, but I need to get the postback working first.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['Default'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.Default;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();             <-----Crashed at this line.
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

What am I missing or is there some common mistake that I may have made somewhere? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `__doPostBack` script is trying to submit a form with id `"Default"` (see `document.forms["Default"]` line; yet your markup shows a form with id `"form1"` so it's clear why it doesn't work: the `__doPostBack` function is not finding the form and calling `theForm.submit()` fails.

You can attempt to fix it by renaming the form to use the id `"Default"` since I don't think you can control the way the `__doPostBack` script is generated.

Comment: All my other forms have that form ID as well even though the aspx files have a different name but I changed it to match the aspx file name and now it crashes in a different spot: `if(this._disposeChildElements&&typeof(Sys.WebForms)!="undefined"){Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._destroyTree(b)`